# Angular cli showing error "An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'test' target." when running ng test or ng serve command

Tags: angular, build, angular8, angular-test, angular-cli-v8

I have a basic angular application , which was working fine. The `ng serve` and `ng test` commands were working fine. Recently as part of build automation for different environments , I introduced some configuration changes to allow different `environment.ts` files to be loaded as per environment . For that I edited the `angular.json` file.After the changes , the `ng serve` and `ng test` command fails to execute. Whenever the commands are executed the following error is thrown :

```
An unhandled exception occurred: No projects support the 'test' target.
See "C:\Users\account\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-BlbvgV\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

The modified `angular.json` is :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "applicationui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../applicationservice/src/main/resources/static",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev-qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev-qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev-prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev-prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "applicationui:build"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:production"
              },
              "qa": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:qa"
              },
              "dev-qa": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev-qa"
              },
              "dev-prod": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev-prod"
              },
              "dev": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev"
              }
            }
          },
          "extract-i18n": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "applicationui:build"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "codeCoverage": true,
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.css"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            }
          },
          "lint": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                "tsconfig.app.json",
                "tsconfig.spec.json",
                "e2e/tsconfig.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
            }
          },
          "e2e": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
            "options": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "applicationui:serve"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "devServerTarget": "applicationui:serve:production"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "applicationui"
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue, it was a mis-placed } . I closed the "`build`" goal before `configuration` , which was causing the issue.Corrected `angular.json` :

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "applicationui": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "../applicationservice/src/main/resources/static",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev-qa": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev-qa.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev-prod": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.dev-prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            },
            "dev": {
              "optimization": false,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": true,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }},
          "serve": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "applicationui:build"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:production"
              },
              "qa": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:qa"
              },
              "dev-qa": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev-qa"
              },
              "dev-prod": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev-prod"
              },
              "dev": {
                "browserTarget": "applicationui:build:dev"
              }
            }
          },
          "extract-i18n": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
            "options": {
              "browserTarget": "applicationui:build"
            }
          },
          "test": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
            "options": {
              "codeCoverage": true,
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
              "assets": [
                "src/favicon.ico",
                "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                "src/styles.css"
              ],
              "scripts": []
            }
          },
          "lint": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
            "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                "tsconfig.app.json",
                "tsconfig.spec.json",
                "e2e/tsconfig.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
            }
          },
          "e2e": {
            "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
            "options": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "applicationui:serve"
            },
            "configurations": {
              "production": {
                "devServerTarget": "applicationui:serve:production"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
  "defaultProject": "applicationui"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Having the same issue here, but angular.json is not the problem in my case (same PC, parallel project with same angular.json file works just fine).

I think it's due to package.json instead, which are different, after running npm install

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was getting "`An unhandled exception occurred: Invalid target: {"project":"vertx-angularclient-poc","target":"build","configuration":"development"}.`" when I ran ng serve.

After doing analysis, I found project name is not matching with "browserTarget" project name under "serve" goal which shown in the below code.
Under "projects" goal, the project name should match with project name under 'serve' goal.

```
"projects": {
    "vertx-angularclient-poc": { },

"serve": {
                    "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "**vertx-angularclient-poc**:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "**vertx-angularclient-poc**:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
```

Full angular.json is:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",`enter code here`
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "vertx-angularclient-poc": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/vertx-angularclient-poc",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "**vertx-angularclient-poc**:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "**vertx-angularclient-poc**:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "example:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "zone.js",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": ["src/styles.scss"],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "style": "scss"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Worth noting too that this is case-sensitive. In my angular.json a previous developer (not me honest!) had typed the project name in all lowercase but the `browserTarget`s in ProperCase

Answer (score 0):

For me was the error because of ExecutionPolicy of microsoft windows. I read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.1)

also I saw my current pollicy with:

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

I run this order to change it to unrestricted:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
```

now policy set is so:

```
 Scope ExecutionPolicy
        ----- ---------------
MachinePolicy       Undefined
   UserPolicy       Undefined
      Process       Undefined
  CurrentUser       Undefined
 LocalMachine    Unrestricted
```

and it's running fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I found the old project name in `angular.json`, so make sure the project name appears correct in `angular.json`, as shown below. The `xyznewprojectname` in below script from `angular.json` file should be replaced with your `actual project name`

```
`
{
```

"$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
"version": 1,
"newProjectRoot": "projects",
"projects": {
"xyznewprojectname": {
"projectType": "application",
"schematics": {
"@schematics/angular:component": {
"style": "scss"
}
}
....
..
..
}
}
}
`

```
also another place I changed the name was in `karma.conf.js` under `coverageReporter`
```

Answer (score 0):

This is major because of the structuring changes in angular.json file
"test" should in "architect" level not inside other hierarchy

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/your-project",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          "src/assets/images/favicon-32x32.png",
          "src/assets/images/safari-pinned-tab.svg",
          "src/assets",
          "src/staticwebapp.config.json"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.carousel.min.css",
          "./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css",
          "src/styles.scss",
          "src/assets/fonts/font-file.css",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "./node_modules/owl.carousel/dist/owl.carousel.min.js",
          "./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js"
        ]
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "index": {
            "input": "src/index.prod.html",
            "output": "index.html"
          },
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sit2": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.sit2.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "baseHref": "/sit2/",
          "deployUrl": "/sit2/",

          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sit": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.sit.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "7mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "uat": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.uat.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "9mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "9mb",
              "maximumError": "10mb"
            }
          ]
        },
        "ptest": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.ptest.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "4mb",
              "maximumError": "7mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "4mb",
              "maximumError": "7mb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
      "options": {
        "main": "src/test.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
        "assets": [
          "src/assets/images/favicon-32x32.png",
          "src/assets/images/safari-pinned-tab.svg",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-project:build"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "browserTarget": "your-project:build:production"
        },
        "sit2": {
          "browserTarget": "your-project:build:sit2"
        }
    },
    "extract-i18n": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
      "options": {
        "browserTarget": "your-project:build"
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
      "options": {
        "tsConfig": [
          "tsconfig.app.json",
          "tsconfig.spec.json",
          "e2e/tsconfig.json"
        ],
        "exclude": [
          "**/node_modules/**"
        ]
      }
    },
    "e2e": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
      "options": {
        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
        "devServerTarget": "your-project:serve"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "production": {
          "devServerTarget": "your-project:serve:production"
        }
      }
    }
    }
  }
```